# r why did the defined data frame variable types change?

Tags: r

I built an empty data frame with defined variable types. Why the variable types changed when adding a new row of values to the data frame?

```
df <- data.frame(key = character(),
                  mean = double(),
                  std = double(),
                  count = integer(),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
a <- "a"
b <- 1.22
c <- 2.33
d <- 3

df[nrow(df)+1,]<- c(a, b,c,d)
```

result shows all variables had turned to character
[image]

Comment: Nothing to do with the data frame: it's because vectors cannot contain mixed types, so all values are coerced to character. Try simply `c(1, "a")` and it will become `c("1", "a")`.

Comment: If you want to add rows one-by-one, you need a `list` or `data.frame` instead - `df[nrow(df)+1,] <- list(a,b,c,d)` will work for instance.